# Test if npm is connecting through proxy from visual studio 2015

Tags: angular, npm, visual-studio-2015, proxy, installation

Im trying to create my first Angular site, however Im having problems restoring the  json packages using NPM.

I know this is a proxy issue, as i'm behind a corporate firewall.

I'm trying to troubleshoot the correct proxy information.

1. Im updating the settings in NPM using the command window.
2. Go to visual studio and right click packages.json and then restore.
3. Computer takes a long time to tell me the proxy settings are incorrect.

I'm trying to get a quick way of testing my proxy settings in step 3 above, without doing the restore.

Also - I see some people are suggesting you need to input your username and password as part of the proxy settings, is username and password necessary? These are not required when I connect to the internet.

Answer (score 3):

To test if npm can connect you can use

```bash
npm ping
```

If a certain package fails, try to only install this package. In my case cypress made problems:

```bash
npm --proxy <url> install cypress
```

`npm ping` returns something like this

[image: cmd.exe with npm ping]

Answer (score 1):

The need of username and password depends on the proxy. But I think they are needed. Often you don't need it while access the internet because you are already logged in via WLAN or an account of the company or the browser already has all settings. So you should try it with credentials.

You can set the proxy global:

```
npm config set proxy http://<username>:<password>@<proxy-server-url>:<port>
npm config set https-proxy http://<username>:<password>@<proxy-server-url>:<port>
```

Or you can use it directly in the command:

```
npm --proxy http://<username>:<password>@<proxy-server-url>:<port> install
```

You can also find all these settings in the file `.nmprc` under your home directory.

To check if `npm` works with your settings you can use `npm ping` command from the command line. If it returns `{}` everything should be fine.

Comment: Thanks - As far as I know, there is no fast way to check, if the proxy settings work. This is my question though...

Comment: @Dez79 See my updated answer, please. I remembered that you can use a the `npm ping` command.

Comment: the npm ping command returns success {} however i still get the proxy error within visual studio

Comment: Do you also get a proxy error when you use `npm install` from cmd?

Comment: yeah, I get the proxy message error here too...but it takes a while